# How to store button name, from a loop, when clicked on?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Trying to store the name of the buttons that are clicked on, in a list (orderList). These buttons were also generated from a list (menuList) by a FOR loop. Whenever any button is clicked, it stores the last value only.

```
menuList = ['egg', 'bacon', 'bread']
orderList = []

def makeOrder(arg):
    orderList.append(arg)
    print (orderList)

for btn in mealList:
    ttk.Button(mainframe, text=btn, command=lambda: makeOrder(btn)).grid(column=1, row=5)
```

I just want to get each button to store it's name inside the blank list (orderList)

Answer (score 0):

This is due to late binding of python which you can read more about it [here](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/). In short, you can work it out by modifying your `lambda` function:

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

menuList = ['egg', 'bacon', 'bread']
mealList = ["breakfast","lunch","dinner"]
orderList = []

root = tk.Tk()
mainframe = tk.Frame(root)
mainframe.pack()

for num,btn in enumerate(mealList):
    ttk.Button(mainframe, text=btn,command=lambda x=btn: orderList.append(x)).grid(column=num, row=5)

tk.Button(mainframe,text="result",command=lambda: print (orderList)).grid(row=6,column=0)

root.mainloop()
```